# C# Automatic Property Deserialization - Lists

Tags: c#, properties, deserialization, complex-data-types

I'm trying to use automatic deserialization in my MVC action like so:

```
public void CreateEntitlementEntity(EntitlementEntityModel model) {
     // stuff
}
```

And here's the class I want to deserialize:

```
public class EntitlementEntityModel {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<string> Domains { get; set; }

    public EntitlementEntityModel() { }
}
```

I'm passing a JSON object of data to the controller action:

```
data: {
    FirstName: 'first',
    LastName: 'last',
    Email: 'email@email.com',
    Domains: ['a','b','c']
}
```

All of the properties deserialize correctly except the List of strings. I would like to turn a JSON array into a List, but it instead gives me a list with one string in it, the JSON array string.

Is there a way to accomplish this in .Net Framework 3.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use some input from this thread?

[Deserializing json array into .net class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272111/deserializing-json-array-into-net-class)

Comment: I checked the link out, but I don't see how that will help me. I'm not asking how to deserialize an array into a list in a general sense, I'm asking if it's possible to do it using automatic (implicit?) deserialization in MVC actions.

Answer (score 1):

If you dump the JsonValueProviderFactory into your OnApplicationStarted() method in your global.asax, it should deserialize json objects into the input parameters of your controller action just fine.

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
    base.OnApplicationStarted();

    // for managing complex json objects
    ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

Comment: Is there a solution similar to this that works in .Net Framework 3.5?

Comment: I'm not sure you need 4.0 in order to do this. It's a ProviderFactory available in MVC 2 Futures. It is registered by default in MVC 3.